# About Multiple Key Encryption

Tags: encryption, key

I am planning to create a project that uses blockchain to store data which, when shared mutually, brings significant benefits but poses risks and must maintain its integrity if disclosed to just anyone.

For this, encryption technology is necessary.

Is there a method to encrypt data using the public keys or specific keys of two individuals, and decrypt the encrypted data using the private key or a specific key of one of these two individuals?

Currently, I am designing the system using a mix of symmetric and asymmetric keys, but I would be very grateful for any other suggestions or opinions.

Comment: What's wrong with that? Just encrypt a symmetric data key with the public keys of both individuals...

Comment: Check out [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).